# Apache Camel Proxy isn't working

Tags: java, apache-camel

Issue might be related to my understanding of the concept too. 
`ActionClass` is invoking proxy bean which is `AccountingInterface`. Proxy bean interface is implemented with `AccountingUtil` class. So I am expecting `xml` returned by `AccountingUtil` to be passed through `seda:accountingQueue` and then streamed out on console.

**ApplicationContext**

```
    <bean id="accountingInterface" class="org.apache.camel.spring.remoting.CamelProxyFactoryBean">
      <property name="serviceUrl" value="seda:accountingQueue"/>
      <property name="serviceInterface" value="acord.transaction.util.AccountingInterface"/>
    </bean>
    <route>
        <from uri="seda:accountingQueue"/>
        <setHeader headerName="nowInMillis">
           <groovy>new Date().getTime()</groovy>
         </setHeader>
         <to uri="stream:out"/>
    </route>
```

**AccountingInterface**

```
public interface AccountingInterface 
{
    void send(String xml);
    String accountingUpdate(EDITDate accountingProcessDate);
}
```

**AccountingUtil**

```
public class AccountingUtil implements AccountingInterface
{
  public String accountingUpdate(EDITDate accountingProcessDate)
     {
       //doSomething
      return xml;
    }
```

**ActionClass**

```
AccountingInterface accountingInterface = (AccountingInterface) AppContext.getBean("accountingInterface");
accountingInterface.accountingUpdate(accountingProcessDate);
```

But I am getting exception:

```
No body available of type: java.lang.String but has value: BeanInvocation public abstract java.lang.String acord.transaction.util.AccountingInterface.accountingUpdate(edit.common.EDITDate) with [2012/11/08]] of type: org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation on: Message: BeanInvocation public abstract java.lang.String acord.transaction.util.AccountingInterface.accountingUpdate(edit.common.EDITDate) with [2012/11/08]]. Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation to the required type: java.lang.String with value BeanInvocation public abstract java.lang.String acord.transaction.util.AccountingInterface.accountingUpdate(edit.common.EDITDate) with [2012/11/08]]. Exchange[Message: BeanInvocation public abstract java.lang.String acord.transaction.util.AccountingInterface.accountingUpdate(edit.common.EDITDate) with [2012/11/08]]]. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type: org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanInvocation to the required type: java.lang.String with value BeanInvocation public abstract java.lang.String acord.transaction.util.AccountingInterface.accountingUpdate(edit.common.EDITDate) with [2012/11/08]]]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:101)
```

**One more issue** Can I have multiple `serviceURL` for single `proxyBean(interface)`? 
I want different method to call different `serviceURL` but part of a single interface.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Ah, just understood your question. Was a bit first in the first place.

When doing Proxying Camel translates the call (to which method/interface and what arguments) into a BeanInvocation object. That is then passed over the Camel endpoint of choice (seda in your case) to be processed. But you are trying to print it to std out rather than invoke a bean instance of `AccountingInterface` (such as `AccountingUpdateACORDUtil` in your case).

And no, different methods will call the same URL but with .. well, different methods in the `BeanInvocation`. This can of course be achieved by routing your request in a Camel route such as first sending it to a simple `direct:routeAccoutingRequest` then look at the invoked method to figure out which endpoint it should go to in a choice construct.

You can build your own logic using a plain object with ProducerTemplates to achive things such as sending Strings, invoking different methods etc. The proxy is for proxying bean invocations.

Comment: That should not be a problem I think. For a simple use case plain proxy bean was working. This approach is mentioned in `Camel In Action`. Is it a fair assumption that `return of proxy interface method` will go to service url?

Comment: Read the question a bit too fast. Changed the answer quite radically

Comment: I got your point on having onw serviceURL for each proxy bean. Could not understand why my flow is giving error. Updated my question to explain the code flow.

Comment: I guess problem is my understanding of the whole Hiding Middleware concept itself :( Check out my other [question][1] specific to this idea.[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300004/apache-camel-hiding-middleware-apis