# Apache Camel: Hiding Middleware APIs

Tags: java, apache-camel

It is related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285259/apache-camel-proxy-isnt-working/17286152). 
 How does `Hiding Middleware` APIs work exactly?

 Do I have to create interfaces so that they can send message to a `serviceURL`?
So I can not use proxy interfaces for anything else.Right? I was wondering if I can do some processing in the implementation class and return the result of that to `serviceURL`.
And If I have 20+ camel routes in my `applicationContext.xml`,

> Would I end up including 20+ interfaces as proxy beans?

May be that's how Camel works. But I didn't expect it to be that way.
I am having a hard time convincing myself that I just have to add some Camel specific `Interface Classes`.